# Strucchange with autoregressive model

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to test for structural changes in a time series based on an autoregressive model with `strucchange` package in R.
It is something like:

```
a<-ts(rnorm(150))
b<-breakpoints(a~lag(a,-1))
coeftest(b)
```

What seems to happen is the misunderstanding of the lag operator by the `breakpoints` command.
What should I do? Is there an alternative for `strucchange` package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That misunderstanding is not unique to `breakpoints()`, `lm()` does the same thing:

```
lm(a ~ lag(a, -1))
## Call:
## lm(formula = a ~ lag(a, -1))
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)   lag(a, -1)  
##  -1.813e-17    1.000e+00
```

The reason is that `a` and `lag(a, -1)` have the same length (and just a shifted time index) so that `cbind()` yields two identical columns (and ignores the time index). To yield the correct result simply set up a suitable multivariate time series and use that:

```
d <- ts.intersect(a = a, lag = lag(a, -1))
lm(a ~ lag, data = d)
## Call:
## lm(formula = a ~ lag, data = d)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          lag  
##    -0.14136      0.06969
```

The same approach then also works in `breakpoints(a ~ lag, data = d)`.